# VBA Type Runtime 13 Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if someone can help me with this question. I have written a macro with the objective of deleting selected rows based upon whether or not all cells in a row contain the value "**<0.01**".  The problem is when the program tries to process the if statement it errors out.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Sub deleteRows()
    Dim rng As Long
    Dim FirstCol, LastCol As Long
    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    FirstCol = UsedRng(1).Column
    LastCol = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Column

    rng = Application.Selection.Rows.Count

    For i = rng To 1 Step -1
    if Range(Cells(i, FirstCol), Cells(i, LastCol)) = "<0.01" Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    Next i
    End Sub


New code that i wrote

`Sub for3()
Dim ma, r, c As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim deletenum As Long
Dim firstcol As Variant
Set ma = Application.Selection
Set r = ma.Rows
Set c = ma.Columns
counter = 0
deletenum = c.Count
firstcol = ma(1).Column

For Each r In ma


    For Each c In r

        If c.Column = firstcol Then
        counter = 0


        End If

        If c.Text = "<0.01" Then

        counter = counter + 1

        End If

        If counter = deletenum Then
        r.EntireRow.Delete
     ma.Offset(1, 0).Activate

        End If
     Next c
Next r

End Sub
```

`

Comment: You will need to loop across the columns - you can't test an array (such as the `Range` values) with a String.  (You should also check your loop counter - you are looping based on the number of rows in a range but using the counter to reference the rows in the worksheet.  So, if your selected range was `A21:D30`, i.e. 10 rows, you will be checking rows 10 to 1 of the worksheet.)

Comment: furthermore even if your scalar-to-array comparison would work (@YowE3K explained it will not) you are comparing with string value, not numeric

Comment: @avb I don't think the OP is trying to test for numbers < 0.01.  The way the question is written makes me think that the cells do actually contain the string `"<0.01"`.

Comment: I think you're right, and if so...

Comment: Hi there.  I am searching for the string <0.01 not values less than 0.01  I have some reading to do.  I will let you all know what ends up working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Trento have you tried any of the solutions you were given below ? any feedback ?

Comment: Hi everyone, i started with the advice from YowE3K and started looping through the columns in each row.  Success, but i have to run the macro multiple times in order to delete all the required rows.

Comment: the code i am now using is listed in my edited questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Find` function per row instead:

```
Dim FndRng  As Range

For i = rng To 1 Step -1
    Set FndRng = Range(Cells(i, FirstCol), Cells(i, LastCol)).Find(What:="<0.01", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FndRng Is Nothing Then ' find was successful
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next
```

---

**Edit 1**: check that all cells in row equal to `"<0.01"`.

```
For i = rng To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(i, FirstCol), Cells(i, LastCol)), "<0.01") = Range(Cells(i, FirstCol), Cells(i, LastCol)).Cells.Count Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next I
```

---

***Edit 2***:

```
Option Explicit

Sub t()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim firstCol As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim firstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim C As Range

Set Rng = Selection ' only if you realy need to

' calculate the first and last column of the Selection
firstCol = Rng(1).Column
LastCol = Rng.Columns.Count + firstCol - 1

' calculate the first and last Row of the Selection
firstRow = Rng(1).Row
LastRow = Rng.Rows.Count + firstRow - 1

' loop backwards, for the Selection last row, until the first row of the selection
For i = LastRow To firstRow Step -1
    ' loop through current's row cells
    For Each C In Range(Cells(i, firstCol), Cells(i, LastCol))
        If C.Value2 <> "<0.01" Then
            GoTo ExitLoop
        End If
    Next C

    Rows(i).Delete

ExitLoop:
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: OP needs all cells in a row to be equal to "<0.01", not only one.

Comment: @EganWolf  now I see what he meant, thanks. I'll update it soon

Comment: Nice one! Good job :)

Comment: @ShaiRado i tried your solution and am receiving a type 13 mismatch at runtime.  Full code below: `Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
Dim firstcol, LastCol As Long
Dim i As Range

Set rng = Application.Selection
Set i = rng.Rows
firstcol = rng(1).Column
LastCol = rng(rng.Cells.Count).Column
For i = rng To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(i, firstcol), Cells(i, LastCol)), "<0.01") = Range(Cells(i, firstcol), Cells(i, LastCol)).Cells.Count Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub`

Comment: @ShaiRado  thank you very much.  works great.  I don't understand the need to subtract 1 from the last row `LastRow = Rng.Rows.Count + firstRow - 1`  why is this not just `Rng.Rows.Count`?

Comment: @Trento think you are selecting `Range("A2:D10")`, so `Rng.Rows.Count` is 9, but you want to loop from Row 10 until row 2. So you need to add this offset in case you will select a range which doesn't start from the 1st row.

Answer (score 0):

your test expression might look like:

```
Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(Cells(i, FirstCol), Cells(i, LastCol)).Value)), " ") Like "*<0.01*"
```